# Problem with Button Design in Kotlin/Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and recently tried designing a button. However, when I create a file for the button in the drawable folder and link it to the activity_main.xml code, I don't see any changes in the design view. When I try to change its color, it doesn't change, and I also want to change its shape, but that doesn't work either. I've tried several alternatives, but couldn't get any results. Only when I perform 'Rebuild project' or 'Clear Project', my adjustments are updated for a few seconds and then it reverts to its old state. Any help would be appreciated.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgo3R.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiME5.png)

What have you tried?
I've tried creating a drawable resource file for the button in the drawable folder with the desired design. I linked this file to the activity_main.xml layout code, but unfortunately, the changes are not reflected in the design view. I attempted to change the button's color and shape directly in the XML code, but the design preview remains unchanged.

What were you expecting?
I expected to see the updated button design in the design view as soon as I made changes to the XML code. Specifically, I wanted to change the color and shape of the button, but these modifications are not being applied. The strange behavior of the design update only lasting a few seconds after 'Rebuild project' or 'Clear Project' is confusing, and I'm looking for a solution to make my design changes permanent.